# Integrating Netrw with the Terminal

Tags: vim, terminal, zsh, neovim

As far as I can tell, navigating directories is much easier with netrw than it is inside of the shell.

For this reason, I am trying to integrate netrw with the shell, and so far what I have is simply:

(Edited after getting some help on Libera chat)

```
    augroup netrw_mapping
            autocmd!
            autocmd filetype netrw call NetrwMapping()
    augroup END

    function! NetrwMapping()
            nnoremap <buffer> <leader>tr <Plug>NetrwLcd<cmd>term<CR>i
    endfunction
```

This opens a shell inside of the currently explored directory. I'm not sure this is really the best solution, or whether I might be missing something from the netrw documentation, but I did look there, and couldn't seem to find anything on terminal integration.

I also have the problem that when I would like to terminate the shell, I lose the window entirely, rather than navigating back to netrw, or from wherever else I came.

I suspect that many Vim users are using an explorer with an integrated terminal, in a way that is similar to the one provided by vscode?

If I could alternatively navigate directory structure with zsh in a netrw-like way, that would also solve the problem. I see that I can just type the directory name in zsh in order to change directory, but otherwise I think there must be some other tricks available?

Comment: Can't you just use a directory browser in your shell?

Comment: @waldo49 Your edit really looks like a good answer. I too was looking for this. Not that I don't have quick ways to navigate in the terminal (which all the answers focus on), but sometimes I just *happen* to have found a location in netrw (e.g. via `gf`) and I want to jump there directly

Answer (score 0):

While in a vim buffer, if I want to browse the filesystem, I tend to launch a second terminal in the current working directory, and then navigate around using a program called `nnn`: https://github.com/jarun/nnn

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ranger, a text-based but still graphical file manager, which uses vim's keybindings for navigation: https://github.com/ranger/ranger
It makes navigating a lot easier than has at the same time a much better user interface with many more features.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).